# Differentiation of Product Series

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How to differentiate?

$$\frac{d [ (1-x)\times(1-x^2)\times (1-x^3)....(1-x^n) ]}{dx}$$

I tried to construct an expanding Series and then differentiate but i failed.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Hint : See [Logarithmic Differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation)

Comment: The hint is quite correct, so I'll elaborate further. $y=(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)...$. We can say $\ln y = \ln((1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)...) = \ln (1-x) + \ln(1-x^2) + \ln(1-x^3)$. Differentiating this yields $\frac{dy}{dx}\frac1y = -(\frac1{1-x}+\frac{2x}{1-x^2}+\frac{3x^2}{1-x^3})$. Then move over the $y$, which was the original equation. You're done!

Comment: that hint is not generalized at last

Answer (score 0):

*hint:*

let $u=(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)....$
$$\ln u=\ln(1-x)+\ln (1-x^2)+....$$
$$\frac{1}{u}\times\frac{du}{dx}=-\frac{1}{1-x}+-2x\frac{1}{1-x^2}+.....+(-n\times x^{n-1})\frac{1}{1-x^n}$$

$$\frac{du}{dx}=u\times[-\frac{1}{1-x}+-2x\frac{1}{1-x^2}+.....+(-n\times x^{n-1})\frac{1}{1-x^n}]$$

Thus this is your anaswer

Comment: how to proceed thereafter?